# How to implement Oauth/OpenID/Custom authentication with Backbone.js/Javascript frontend?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, openid, oauth-2.0

I have a site and our backend and frontend ( 100% backbone) are decoupled RestFul (JSON + Ajax), and we are thinking about how to implement the user authentication now.

We want to support facebook, Google and others (OAuth and OpenId) and also our custom method to users who don't have or don't want to use their other accounts.

How do you do your custom authentication? What are the best pratices for that ?

Do you use OAuth or OpenID for your custom login too ?

Answer (score 1):

Oauth has worked for me in the past when using my own custom authentication.  There is a very good library available to handle most of the work.

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/

If you are using node.js as the restFul server you can use Passport Middleware http://passportjs.org/ to handle most of the server side.

The documentation for Passport also includes some good generic examples and strategies that could be implemented on any stack.
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#strategies-1